# Send file from client to client over http

Tags: javascript, http

Do any one knows how to implement file sending via http from client to client. This is similar example but can not find how to implement it: http://jetbytes.com/
Any ideas?

Comment: javascript and files? Well, I don't think so! :-)

Comment: any ideas with node.js or signalR?

Comment: https://Httprelay.io requires no additional libraries and can be used for file transfers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you could just copy their behaviour, which is roughly the following.

Let's name the three parts of the exchange : Sender (in a browser), Server (well... server code), Receiver (in a browser).

- Sender UI: the user selects a file ;
- Sender: periodically (every second here), update the server saying that Sender is ready to send the file. While the Server is not ready, it just answers "I am not ready" to the Sender ;
- Receiver GETs the generated URL ;
- Sender (as before) updates the server saying that it is ready to send the file. This time the server answers "I am ready" ;
- Sender simply POST the file (as it would do in the most simple HTML form).

  - The Server relays the POST data to the Receiver (with relevant headers) ;
  - This operation takes time, so the following operations are just meant to update the progress bar Sender-side.
- Sender asks periodically (every second here) how much data the Server got so far ; the Server answers how much it has received and how much it expects until the end.
- Sender updates its progress bar.
- ...
- Sender asks how much data the Server got so far ; the Server answers it is done.
- Closing routines on three parts of the exchange.

Of course there must be room for improvement :

- Periodic updates could be replaced by another technology (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) ;
- If the transfer is interrupted before it finishes, make it possible to continue where the transfer got interrupted ;
- ...many other aspects

For the implementation, much of the work will be on the client side, and everything described here is achievable using jQuery. On the server, the two goals are transferring data and answering to the Sender. You will have to define yourself a lightweight protocol to say "I am [not] ready", "I got N bytes so far", "I am done".

Answer (score 1):

The example you provide also works with a server. The data is probably streamed directly on the the recipient, but goes through the server nonetheless. The only advantage is that they don't have to keep gigabytes of data on their server.

If you are curious abot the implementation, start Firebug and look at the *Network* tab.

Once you have selected a file, the filename is sent to the server, returning the URL for the download:

```
files1 http://files1.jetbytes.com/42621cb32af927558
```

Then the browser actually **polls** the server every second, asking if somebody has requested the download yet. Once the response turns from `wait 0` to `wait 1`, the Javascript in the browser knows that the download has been requested and POSTs the form with the file.

The server side then pipes the POST data to be directly sent to the downloader. About th implementation we can only guess, but Node.js would probably be a good choice.